# Bi-linear interpolation to point locations from gridded data in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I want to interpolate regular gridded data (like gcm data) to point locations in R. What are the packages or functions in R to do that???
For example I have (2degreex2degree)gridded data in the domain lattitude (66degree to 100 degree) and longitude(5 degree to 40 degree).Now I want to interpolate this data in a location having lattitude 13 degree and longitude 80 degree.
How to do that???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `raster` package has such function.

Comment: How complicated does your routine need to be? Is simple point-in-polygon enough, or do you need to take into account change of support (the variance of point observations will be higher as the gridded data is an areal average)?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra....... i need bi-linear interpolation only

Comment: @Pascal......can u specifically say which function does it in 'raster'????